# aggregate multiple columns over dynamic pivot in sql

Tags: t-sql, dynamic, pivot

I'm creating a stored procedure that would allow the user to retrieve data from 2 tables by providing the `PersonID` number as a parameter.
I thought of using the pivot function to pivot the `Data` table **dynamically** by **non-aggregating** over multiple columns and retrieving data from **ONE** column in a different table. The 2 tables below are just sample data as I have  over 100 columns for the data table, hence the dynamic part. The 2 tables doesn't have a common ID column but just a common column_name. 
Here are the 2 tables:

Mapping Table:

```
CREATE table #table (
ID varchar(10) NOT NULL,
Column_Name varchar (255) NOT NULL, 
Page_Num varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
Line_Num varchar(10) NOT NULL,
Element_Num varchar(10) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #table (ID,Column_Name,Page_Num,Line_Num,Element_Num) VALUES ('1','Name', 'DT-01', '200','20')
INSERT INTO #table (ID,Column_Name,Page_Num,Line_Num,Element_Num) VALUES ('2','SSN', 'DT-02', '220','10')
INSERT INTO #table (ID,Column_Name,Page_Num,Line_Num,Element_Num) VALUES ('3','City', 'DT-03', '300','11')
INSERT INTO #table (ID,Column_Name,Page_Num,Line_Num,Element_Num) VALUES ('4','StreetName', 'DT-04', '350','33')
INSERT INTO #table (ID,Column_Name,Page_Num,Line_Num,Element_Num) VALUES ('5','Sex', 'DT-05', '310','51')
```

Creates:

```
ID   Column_Name      Page_Num    Line_Num    Element_Num
_________________________________________________________________
    1    Name              DT-01         200          20
    2    SSN               DT-02         220          10
    3    City              DT-03         300          11
    4    StreetName        DT-04         350          33
    5    Sex               DT-05         310          51
```

Data table:

```
    CREATE table #temp (
PersonID varchar (100) NOT NULL,
Name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
SSN varchar (255) NOT NULL, 
City varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
StreetName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
Sex varchar(100) NOT NULL
)


INSERT INTO #temp (PersonID,Name,SSN,City,StreetName,Sex) VALUES ('112','Joe','945890189', 'Lookesville', 'Broad st','Male')
INSERT INTO #temp (PersonID,Name,SSN,City,StreetName,Sex) VALUES ('140','Santana','514819926', 'Falls Church', 'Gane Rd', 'Female')
INSERT INTO #temp (PersonID,Name,SSN,City,StreetName,Sex) VALUES ('481','Wyatt','014523548','Gainesville', 'Westfield blvd', 'Male')
INSERT INTO #temp (PersonID,Name,SSN,City,StreetName,Sex) VALUES ('724','Brittany','551489230','Aldi', 'Ostrich rd', 'Female')
INSERT INTO #temp (PersonID,Name,SSN,City,StreetName,Sex) VALUES ('100','Giovanni','774451362','Paige', 'Company ln', 'Male')
```

Creates:

```
PersonID  Name         SSN            City           StreetName      Sex
    _______________________________________________________________________
    112     Joe      945890189     Lookesville         Broad st      Male
    140    Santana   514819926     Falls Church        Gane Rd       Female
    481     Wyatt    014523548     Gainesville         Westfield rd  Male
    724    Brittany  551489230     Aldi                Ostrich rd    Female
    100    Giovanni  774451362     Paige               Company ln    Male
```

The end result should be:
Example: User enters parameter `PersonID` = 140

```
   Column_name   Page_Num      Line_Num       Element_Num       Data
    _____________________________________________________________________________
    Name         DT-01          200              20             Santana
    SSN          DT-02          220              10             514819926
    City         DT-03          300              11            Falls Church
    StreetName   DT-04          350              33              Gane Rd
    Sex          DT-05          310              51              Female
    ...          ...            ...              ...              ...
```

and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will dynamically unpivot a data row, and then perform a join on the field name with the def data.

If you want to run this query without a filter, I would suggest adding `A.PersonID` to the top `SELECT` and remove the `WHERE`

I should add, **UNPIVOT** would be more performant, but with this approach, there is no need to define and/or recast values.   That said, the performance is still very respectable.

**Example**

```
Select D.*
      ,Data=C.Value
 From  #Temp A
 Cross Apply (Select XMLData = cast((Select A.* For XML Raw) as xml)) B
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item   = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value  = attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row') as X(r)
                 Cross Apply X.r.nodes('./@*') AS N(attr)
             ) C
 Join  #Table D on (C.Item=D.Column_Name)
 Where PersonID=140
```

**Returns**

[image]

**If it Helps with the Visualization, the CROSS APPLY C generates the following:**

[image]

> **EDIT - As a Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[YourProcedureName](@PersonID int) 

As

Begin
    Set NoCount On;

    Select D.*
          ,Data=C.Value
     From  YourPersonTableName A
     Cross Apply (Select XMLData = cast((Select A.* For XML Raw) as xml)) B
     Cross Apply (
                    Select Item   = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                          ,Value  = attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                     From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row') as X(r)
                     Cross Apply X.r.nodes('./@*') AS N(attr)
                 ) C
     Join  YourObjectTableName D on (C.Item=D.Column_Name)
     Where PersonID=@PersonID

End
```

Comment: @BetaData See updated answer.  I added a a Stored Procedure.  You will need to supply the YourPersonTableName and YourObjectName

Comment: Thank You, Could you explain the Cross apply in C,I understand the usage of cross apply but not sure what "attr.value" is doing. Are you attributing the columns to that data type?

Comment: @BetaData Cross Apply B will convert the row into an XML Raw where each field is an ATTRIBUTE not a node. For example: a data row will look like this <row PersonID="112" Name="Joe" SSN="945890189" City="Lookesville" StreetName="Broad st" Sex="Male" />  .....  Then Cross Apply C will convert each attribute/value into a row.

Comment: @BetaData I should add that each value is converted to varchar(max).  The max is just a generic value.  Could be varchar(100) if you'd rather.

Comment: I see, that's helpful and informative! Somehow the final table is not populating ALL the rows in `ColumnName` from table #temp? is that because there isn't a match of column names based on the join: `YourObjectTableName D on (C.Item=D.Column_Name)` ?

Comment: @BetaData Assumed that was by design.   So if the field is NOT in  the "ObjectTable", what do you want displayed?   A LEFT JOIN would show NULL Values